# Проблема при разработке модуля bitrix

Tags: битрикс, модули

Народ, всем привет!

Начал изучать разработку своих собственных модулей. Читал вот эту статью: [Битрикс. Создание своего модуля. Часть 1 из 3](https://tokmakov.msk.ru/blog/item/207) - и прям пошагово 1 в 1 пробовал создать точно такой же модуль, как там описано.

Дошёл до шага, где создаётся файл Файл local/modules/scrollup/install/unstep.php

Там написано, что после создания этого файла в админ-панеле Битрикс на странице Настройки • Настройки продукта • Модули в списке модулей должен появиться только что созданный, но не установленный модуль.

Я дошёл до этого шага, зашёл в админку в Настройки - Настройки продукта - Модули, но мой модуль не появился.

Может кто с таким сталкивался? Где можно почитать про разработку своих собственных модулей на простых примерах, чтоб прям пошагово объяснялось, какие файлы создавать, и в каких директориях. А то ищу в интернете примеры, делаю 1 в 1, но в списке модулей новый модуль так и не появляется.

Пробовал сделать модуль, как в официальной документации написано: [Пример создания модуля](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=101&LESSON_ID=2902) - но итог тот же самый - в списке модулей новый модуль так и не появляется.

Помогите пожалуйста. Разработку веду локально на демо-версии Битрикс (веб-сервер OpenServer 5.4.0).

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы настройки модуля появились в разделе настроек, необходимо добавить в корень модуля файл options.php. В вашем случае:

```
local/modules/scrollup/options.php
```

На странице по указанной вами ссылке есть все необходимые примеры.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)